# HIgh Sierra media(play) button changes

Tags: macos, itunes, keyboard, high-sierra

After updating to High Sierra on my Mac, I realise that Apple had changed the media(play) button to unified all the media that playing everywhere including Safari webpage. Previously the button only affect songs playing app like Spotify or iTunes, now it stop my video instead of the song when I pressed it.

I already sent feedback to Apple, https://www.apple.com/feedback/ so I’m looking for a workaround /  fix / script or tool to revert the play pause change that Apple has made.

To be clear, I'm using MBPnTB 2016 version which means I have the physical media function button.

Can I get the play physical keyboard media buttons back to controlling iTunes only?

Comment: Beardedspice: http://beardedspice.github.io/

Answer (score 5):

One solution for the problem is [this tiny menu bar app](http://milgra.com/high-sierra-media-key-enabler.html).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the software you recommended is better than others out there.  We prefer more than just a link-only answer so add a description of the software and why you're recommending it.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Comment: its work for me.

Comment: Before I knew this existed, I also wrote a little menu bar app to solve the same problem! http://stuntsoftware.com/reflex/