# Touch Bar no longer allows for switching between media controls in High Sierra?

Tags: macos, itunes, youtube, high-sierra, touch-bar

Prior to updating to High Sierra, the touch bar would display any media that is currently playing (such as iTunes) and allow me to expand it and control it.

As I'm typing in Safari, the touch bar displays no options to control the music that is currently playing in iTunes. Obviously I could expand the control strip to display the play/pause button but previously the blank space would display the media.

It's annoying when you have two sources playing simultaneously such as iTunes and YouTube. Previously I could switch media control between the two of them so that when a YouTube video is playing I could pause iTunes from the touch bar without switching to the app. Currently there is no way to switch media control without having it in the active window more recently than all other media.

Is this something others are experiencing or an issue with my machine?

Comment: Please do not add the answer to the question (or the subject).

Comment: @patrix thanks for the feedback! rationale was saving others a click. noted!

Comment: People will still click through to read the question, just to verify that the issue is the same they experience. And then see the accepted answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. Running Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be several people (including myself) that are frustrated by this change. Unfortunately, it appears that a full-time fix has not been found across several posts that I perused (below).

- [Touch Bar Media Play/Pause button controls Safari, not iTunes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280494/touch-bar-media-play-pause-button-controls-safari-not-itunes?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [HIgh Sierra media(play) button changes](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300811/high-sierra-mediaplay-button-changes?rq=1)

Someone did come up with this [semi-solution](https://bekirserifoglu.wordpress.com/2017/10/01/solutionworkaround-for-mac-os-high-sierra-unified-media-buttons-playpause-next-and-previous-track-problem/), but it unfortunately it only works for the the menu bar in non-Touch Bar form; that being said, it may be a good idea just to keep an eye on that page (hopefully a solution for those of us with the Touch Bar will show up).